# access special attributes using string

Tags: python

I want to perform something like :

```
lst = ['__len__()','__str__()', '__repr__()']

for i in lst:
  print(i, 'a'.i)
```

But it throws error as `'__len__()'` is string. Is there any way I can convert it to  `'a'.__len__()`?

Comment: `getattr('a', i)` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getattr](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.getattr) to complete your task

```
lst = ['__len__','__str__', '__repr__']

for i in lst:
  print(i, getattr('a', i)())
```